# Weird (erroneous) behavior in evaluating particular infinite sum

Tags: summation

What is the cause of this behavior? Notice that in the result there is `n` which is the index of summation, so `n` should never appear in any result. I have no clue what the meaning of the result is.

Input:

```
Sum[Sin[n/(n + 1) x]/n, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]
```

Output:

```
1/2 I (Log[1 - E^((I x)/(1 + n))] - 
   Log[E^(-((I x)/(1 + n))) (-1 + E^((I x)/(1 + n)))])
```

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sin \left(\frac{n}{n+1}x\right)}{n}=\frac{1}{2} i \left(\log \left(1-e^{\frac{i x}{n+1}}\right)-\log \left(e^{-\frac{i x}{n+1}} \left(-1+e^{\frac{i x}{n+1}}\right)\right)\right)$

Comment: It just returns unevaluated in 12.3.1 so it's probably a bug if you're using an older version.

Comment: I use 12.0.0.0.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I guess it diverges for all `x` except `x=0`, but have no proof. But the bug persist even for convergent sum like `Sum[Sin[n/(n + 1) x]/n^2, {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]`

Comment: I guess it might converge for multiples of pi

Comment: In addition to v12.3.1, it also returns unevaluated with v12.1.1, 12.2, 12.3 on a Mac (I don't have access to v12.1).

Comment: Then they use probably old version of mathematica on wolfram alpha too (the same result as on my 12.0.0.0) :-D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSin%5Bn%2F%28n+%2B+1%29+x%5D%2Fn%2C+%7Bn%2C+1%2C+%5C%5BInfinity%5D%7D%5D